# Java socket.io client

Tags: java, socket.io

Is there any Socket.IO-client available for Java?
So far I have only found the official Socket.IO client which is only available for JavaScript and socket.io-java which is only the server.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Limited options at this time:

- http://code.google.com/p/weberknecht/
- https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket
- https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client

sound right as far as WebSockets go. Socket.IO's specific wire protocol do not appear to have been implemented in Java yet, so you may have to deal with that yourself.

Comment: I finally went with Java-WebSocket by TooTallNate and implemented the Socket.IO-specific stuff myself.

Comment: Nice. Would love to hear how that worked out for you: are you using Java on both the client and the server, or java on the client and something like Node.js on the server?

Comment: I'm using Java on the desktop client, JavaScript (of course) on the web clients, and Python on the server.

Comment: @DontCare4Free Have you open-sourced your Socket.io Java client?

Comment: @Kevin, https://github.com/dontcare4free/blservermanager-client/blob/master/src/main/java/tk/dontcare4free/blservermanager/Client.java, although I've had reports of it not working too well with the official node socket.io server.

Comment: I cant compile the socket.io-java-client project with ant.

Comment: Note that the Gottox client does not support the XHR-Transport protocol.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from http://socket.io under "Supported Transports" it could be several different transport protocols:

WebSocket, 
Adobe® Flash® Socket, 
AJAX long polling, 
AJAX multipart streaming, 
Forever Iframe, 
JSONP Polling

So, the question is, what is your server supporting?

From the perspective of Java clients the easiest would be WebSockets.

Comment: Yes, the server supports WebSockets. I'm not sure though about if socket.io does any own magic or just connecting directly should do.

Answer (score 3):

There is now an official Java client:

- https://socketio.github.io/socket.io-client-java/installation.html
- https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

Answer (score 2):

If you need a client side implementation, checkout java-socket.io.client I made it a few months ago and I believe some people have forked it and upgraded it to the latest version:
https://github.com/clwillingham/java-socket.io.client

Answer (score 1):

You can use socket.io-client.java.

See this [link](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java) for src code.

You can also find a tutorial [here](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/03/websockets-on-android.html. I only needed the WebSockets, so I stripped out the WebView part as well, the Factory was superfluous also. You can just get away with using https://github.com/anismiles/websocket-android-phonegap/blob/master/src/com/strumsoft/websocket/phonegap/WebSocket.java and implement the SocketIO specifcs yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is an other Library it is Jetty: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html