# Is it possible to use WebSockets or similar with a native Android application?

Tags: java, android, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a Node.js app that uses HTTP / REST (using Express.js), and a native Android application that communicates with this. This works fine.

I am now looking at writing a more real-time version, which can push messages to a native client. Unfortunately, it needs to be a native client, as there is some fairly complex work done with the data that simply will not be possible in a mobile browser for the forseable future (otherwise I would just wait for WebSockets support to appear in the Android browser).

So, my question is what are my options?

I know about the Android Cloud to Device Messaging framework, but this requires registration and a Google sign-in, and I would much prefer the server to be client agnostic.

Is there a reliable WebSocket client that I can use (ideally) to talk to a Node.js server running Socket.io? Or any other native method (using the NIO classes)?

Comment: Doesn't a native android app have tcp support? Just talk to `node` over a `net` socket.

Answer (score 5):

See [Java socket.io client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783086/java-socket-io-client)

Answer (score 5):

you could use https://github.com/koush/android-websockets. It is also mentioned in the [socket.io wiki pages](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki)

PS: i know it is a bit late to respond to this post, but this for other like me who didn't find an answer to question like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
compile node.js on Android natively
    implement jni wrapper of node.js
    ...
```

refer this link

https://github.com/paddybyers/anode/issues/15