# Android Java socket communication with Socket.IO

Tags: java, android, sockets, node.js, websocket

I'm writing a messaging app. My server is built on node.JS and socket.io. My client should be an Android application. However, I can't seem to find a decent library that gives me a Java interface to Socket.IO (by way of websockets?). Is there some library that exists? Or do I have to fall back on another solution (which one?)?

I've found this library for cocoa: https://github.com/fpotter/socketio-cocoa. Any alternatives for Android?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java socket.io client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783086/java-socket-io-client)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The accepted answer was lacking. They are Java Socket.IO implementations, which require netty, or only had WebSocket support. I ended up writing my own Socket.IO client on top of a lightweight WebSocket client.

https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync

Comment: Hi koush I tried your implementation but does not work with tornadio2 + socket.io v.9. I am now using https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client which also is fully compatible with Android.

Comment: @e_x_p I am also using Gottox socket.io library for my application. Everything works fine except execution gets blocked on disconnection. I am not getting any exception.. Excecution just blocks..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra this might be late but I did submit an issue https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/issues/28. While it's still not fixed by the author I modified the code in my own app.

Comment: yes, koush's implementation is not working on v.9, I get this error on server:

    `destroying non-socket.io upgrade`

and this error on client:

`WebSocket.onError, Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value to parse may not be null.
    at org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser.parseStatusLine(BasicLineParser.java:378)
    at com.codebutler.android_websockets.WebSocketClient.parseStatusLine(WebSocketClient.java:148)`

Comment: Hi koush, I couldn't find a way to ask a question on github. Do you have any plans (or know of a fork of your project) using http long polling as fallback when a connection via web-sockets fails?

Comment: @sunadorer Nope, but I'll take any pull requests.