# Java websocket client needed

Tags: java, websocket

I couldn't find any websocket client, implemented last version of the protocol written in Java.

I found an answer here [Java socket.io client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783086/java-socket-io-client), but

- http://code.google.com/p/weberknecht/ supports protocol hybi-00 and last build was 5 months ago
- https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket doesn't support wss at all

Could you recommend something? 
Thanks

Comment: Java-WebSocket is actively supported, and now supports wss.

Answer (score 2):

Should it be relevant for you: there are both WS client and server implementations supporting draft 13 and 14:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations

Comment: I don't know why those particulars were selected. Some seem like they should be.

Comment: a very good question/observation! please read the talk page of above wiki page for some reasons .. and to find a more complete list of implementations (I rescued that list first from the WebSocket page, then from the Comparison page .. again .. pls see the talk page): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked to jWebSocket? Their latest release is claiming support for Hixie Drafts 75-76 and Hybi Drafts 7-14.

http://jwebsocket.org/

Comment: Yep, it's good project, but client side is a pure JavaScript based, but I need Java based.

Comment: they are claiming that there is also a jwebsocket java library for both desktop and android. I personally not used those but I will...

Answer (score 1):

Follow my blog. I have a running websocket client written in Java. Not quite ready to release (I'm just busy with other things.) But it should be in the near future. I will announce on my blog when it's ready along with a download link.

http://highlevellogic.blogspot.com/2011/09/websocket-server-demonstration_26.html

Comment: It's been a year and you haven't put up the Java based client?